# Looking for a way to notify a user if they have been disconnected from the internet for long periods of time

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, shell-script

as the title says I am looking for a good way to send a notification to a windows user if the machine has been disconnected from the internet for long periods of time (14+ days).

These are industrial machines running Win 10 LTSB basically in kiosk mode for extended periods. I'm looking for a way to prompt the user to connect to the internet and check for windows updates if they haven't done so in the past two weeks.

Currently my solution is a bit wonky but works. I use scheduled powershell scripts to accomplish it. One script logs the date every time a user connects, and another logs every time it disconnects. A third runs every hour to compare the two and the current date and will display a message to the user if it's been 14+ days since the last disconnect.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are running this as a Scheduled task triggered by the network event on connect/disconnect. However this would rely on Event Logger which I wouldn't rely on for a machine that never restarts.

Instead, why don't you continue the same way but **run only 1 powershell script**. Ex. task running once everyday at 9Am. **Script pings google.com** or 8.8.8.8 if success write value "0" to some.txt file, if ping fails -> read value from some.txt and add + 1. 
So value would now become 1, if value was 4 now it becomes 5 and so on. After adding 1 check if new value is higher than 14 then notify user (via error promot/alert or email..). Or run it twice a day then last statement becomes if value higher than 28 do this... Or as often as you prefer.

I'm sure there is other methods or software to do this but I think this would be the most reliable way. It would never fail for long term use.

--Edit
Notify user via popup. Works native, no assemblies required.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Connect now! Use dailup AOL if you have to!",0,"Done",0x1)
```

For more see [Popup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx)

--Edit *Powershell Script Execution polixy*
When creating a task add these

Program/Script: `Powershell.exe`

Add Arguments: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\some\folder\test.ps1`

[image]

If that doesn't work. Then enable this on GroupPolicy
run gpedit.msc

Follow this path `\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell`

Double Click **Turn on Script Execution**
Enable > Allow All Scripts

*Allow some time for changes to take effect. Restart pc or wait a few min and try to rightclick and run the task manually on the Task Scheduler to verify.*

Comment: Thanks,  I will go ahead and try this. Do you know how exactly you would write an error prompt in power shell? Because my current method doesn't seem to be working a a scheduled task: {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Your_Desired_Message','Your_Desired_Title')}

Comment: Check above, added 2 lines.

Comment: I tried that way also! Works great when I run the script on its own but as a scheduled task, it does not display the popup window. Perhaps I should start a new thread.

Comment: let me check... you are running this as a ps1 right?

Comment: yes, a scheduled task in windows 10 running a .ps1 powershell script. I know my setup to run the script is OK because the other two tasks that log connect/disconnect work just fine

Comment: worked for me. ill update the answer in a sec

Comment: The updated answer should work 100%. Tested on LTSB with latest updates.

Comment: alright, it's gotta be something I'm doing here because it is not working for me. I followed you directions exactly, the only difference is I put quotations around the path because the folder is in C:/program files which contains a space. When I click "run" it changes the tasks status to running but does not do anything. I even added a file writer in the script and that is not being executed either.

Comment: Save this file https://pastebin.com/raw/kgy7Wpnd as whatever.js and double click it. If no success then last resort is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Looks like that worked as intended. Got the prompt "do you feel alright?" clicked yes, "Glad you feel alright"

Comment: Ok great, run your window popup as js then. On task scheduler enter just the path of the js file on Program/Script with no Arguments. No need for powershell. You can execute js inside a BAT or inside your currently working PS1 if you want.

Comment: just change my file name from a .ps1 to a .js? That's a thing?

Comment: Not really, change the JS file I sent you to whatever you want it to say. I don't know what your ps1 looks like but simply add 1 line at the end with the path to js file. Just put this at the bottom C:\Users\User\Desktop\try.js

Comment: right, ok. But I think this ps1 script isn't even being executed at all from the task scheduler. I added a few lines of "echo "test" > test.txt" around it and none of them were written to the text file

Comment: Stop it with the quotes! PS doesnt like quotes. Do you test your lines of code on the console before you run task scheduler? If you have path with spaces simply double slash like so C:\\Program Files (x86)\ 

Do you have PowerShell Installed on this windows? hit win > run > optionalfeatures and verify

Comment: yes, like I said before everything works perfectly fine from the console and even when I right click and select "run in powershell" they work fine. also my two ps1 scripts that run on connect/disconnect work perfectly fine.

Comment: ensure you add into the `Start In` box points to a path, where you want the `test.txt` to be written. That way you can tell whether the .ps1 script is running in the Task\

Comment: Then check event viewer, PS is logging the error for sure. Else try ProcMon (sysinternals) and look at everything that happens on task run 1 by 1. or check group policy for anything matching "script" (click "All Tasks" > export and search it from excel or so. If that doesn't work then echo "It's friday, I'm out"

Comment: So i've gotten the ps1 script to run correctly in the scheduler by checking the "run with highest privileges" box. I know this because the logs i added are logging to the text file. But the popup is not being displayed either with the js method or the original popup method. I will look for the error logs.

Comment: hey JsEveryDay, the solution to display the popup was to check the box when creating the scheduled task "run only when user is logged on" otherwise it will run in the background. Hope you had a nice weekend.